# Why can't I create a HOSTS file reference to localhost? (SMB Alias localhost)

Tags: windows

I have created an entry in HOSTS (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

that looks like this:

> 127.0.0.1 testb

I can PING testb, no problem.

However, when I try to use it in windows explorer (i.e., open a windows explorer window and enter `\\testb`) I get challenged for a login, which I then provide. The login fails. I check the EVENT VIEWER and see the following:

> Audit Failure A privileged service was called. . . . Process: Process
> ID: 0x668 Process Name:
> C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe
>
> Service Request Information: Privileges: SeTcbPrivilege

Tested on Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10.
I have set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa > DWORD > DisableLoopbackCheck=1

Comment: Does it work if you try `\\testb\C$`?

Comment: No, same effect. It challenges for a login which it will never accept.  This looks like a bug in the windows authentication for SMB. Basically, from what I've gleaned elsewhere, when you access an SMB share, it uses the "impersonation" to see if you have access. This involves the privilege, "SeTcbPrivilege", which is usually just reserved for system processes, works fine for "other" computers, but onboard, it's a violation, so it throws the error in the audit log. I would not be surprised if "localhost" is hardcoded in the code somewhere so THAT works. Still researching, but losing hope...

Comment: If you share a directory via Windows Explorer (right-click, choose "Give access to...", can you then use `\\testb\YourShareName`? (I notice that you used testb twice and then testa in the question.)

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry! I did use both testA and then testB, I was trying both the 127...IP address (testB) as well as the actual LAN 192... IP address (testA), both fail in the same way. Re your question, no, if you share a directory, you can see it via the machine's name, but not via the alias (\\testA or \\testB).

Comment: Your PC would not have an account *testb\YourAccountName*. That could be the reason.

Comment: @Daniel - thanks, that's an interesting observation. but it would imply that the name-IP translation takes place after the login, which I don't think is the case. For instance, Let's say I have two servers (\\SERVER1 and \\SERVER2). On \\SERVER1 I set up HOSTS to have the entry (testA,testB) pointing to itself. On Server2, I set up the same entry, but I point testA to the IP of SERVER1. Do the same with testB. This will work fine. When you validate, you need to login with \\SERVER1\yourlogin. So I don't think it's an issue with resolving the machine name. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Not sure I follow. Account names are not related to any host name resolution. Accounts also do not start with two backslashes. That’s share names. The login process is higher level and not really concerned with the underlying transport (that happens to rely on TCP/IP here).

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry, what I meant was, when I enter \\TESTA (or \\TESTB) into an explorer window, then I'm challenged for a login. I specify \SERVER1\yourlogin (sorry, you are correct, should have only been one backslash) and give it the proper password. This is rejected and the audit log shows error (above).  I just tried this on one of our Windows 2012 servers and it works fine, so this is some new security between Windows Server 2012 and Windows server 2019. Previously, the registry change suppressed this. Again, appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I added the privilege to my login and it still fails, but now with this audit failure: Event ID 4656
 Process Name: C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe
 Accesses: READ_CONTROL
 WriteData (or AddFile)
 AppendData (or AddSubdirectory or CreatePipeInstance)
 Access Reasons: READ_CONTROL: Granted by D:(A;;0x1200a9;;;BA)
 SYNCHRONIZE: Granted by D:(A;;0x1200a9;;;BA)
 WriteData (or AddFile): Not granted
 AppendData (or AddSubdirectory or CreatePipeInstance): Not granted
 WriteEA: Not granted
 ReadAttributes: Granted by ACE on parent folder D:(A;;0x1301bf;;;BA)
 WriteAttributes: Not granted